# jQuery - Apply method to one page only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a script which hides displays when the page is loaded and hides when the user closes it.

I have set this up to show every time the user visits the website. But I only want it to apply to my homepage. I do not want the notice message to appear on other pages of the website.

I using WordPress so I cannot edit the HTML of individual pages.

```
jQuery('.header-notice a.close').click(function() {
  jQuery('.header-notice').slideUp(200);
  localStorage.setItem("notice", jQuery('.header-notice p').html());
  return false;
});
if (localStorage.getItem("notice") === jQuery('.header-notice p').html()) {
  jQuery('.header-notice').show();
}
jQuery('.alert .close').live('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).parent('.alert').fadeOut(200);
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress does a very cool thing, in my opinion. It always gives you a plethora of class names in the `body` tag to identify which page we are talking about. In this way you can only target with jQuery something like:

```
$('.home .header-notice')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the url and if it is the home page url apply the script

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; 
if (pathname = 'your url')
{
   /*do stuff*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the url to see if you are or not on your homepage, like this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('homepage.php')) {
   //Execute jquery code
}
```

Comment: WordPress uses index.php for making up all pages?

Comment: Well just use the part of the url that identifies your homepage, may be `index.php?id=40` or whatever, paste your homepage url if you need a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

if you use wordpress, fix at wordpress.

add this into `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/header.php`

```
<?php 
 if(is_home()){
  <script>
   //scripts go here
  </script>
}
?>
```

reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home